servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [login]
I am new to spring boot but I am trying to compile and run an old spring boot java code which is throwing the following error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause

My login.jsp is as follows:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/taglibs.jsp" %>

<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden"
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
</form>

and my WebSecurityConfig.java is as follows:
package elements.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        var usr1 = User.builder()
            .username("user1ka")
            .password(encoder.encode("y445uri125"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        var usr2 = User.builder()
            .username("user2ka")
            .password(encoder.encode("sa678sha769"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(usr1, usr2);
    }
}

and my loginController.java is as follows:
package elements.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/login",
            method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

}

what is causing the above error and how to resolve it?
I have now updated the code in line with @M.Deinum's response as follows:
package elements.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll() // Allow access to /error without authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        var usr1 = User.builder()
            .username("user1ka")
            .password("y445uri125")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        var usr2 = User.builder()
            .username("user2ka")
            .password("sa678sha769")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(usr1, usr2);
    }
}

Unfortunately the issue still persist and some of the useful DEBUG logging is as follows:
2024-10-15 21:51:49.306 [main] INFO  elements.config.WebApplication - Started WebApplication in 12.548 seconds (process running for 14.262)
2024-10-15 21:51:49.561 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2024-10-15 21:51:49.583 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2024-10-15 21:52:00.111 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-10-15 21:52:00.112 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-10-15 21:52:00.112 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2024-10-15 21:52:00.112 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2024-10-15 21:52:00.112 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
2024-10-15 21:52:00.113 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@70047c84
2024-10-15 21:52:00.113 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@a489205
2024-10-15 21:52:00.115 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2024-10-15 21:52:00.116 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 4 ms
2024-10-15 21:52:00.242 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /login
2024-10-15 21:52:00.314 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /login
2024-10-15 21:52:00.319 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-10-15 21:52:00.323 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to elements.controllers.LoginController#login()
2024-10-15 21:52:00.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/png, image/svg+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2024-10-15 21:52:00.392 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.view.InternalResourceView - View name [login], model {}
2024-10-15 21:52:00.394 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name [login]; URL [login]]
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
.
.
.
2024-10-15 21:52:00.417 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Failed to complete request: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
2024-10-15 21:52:00.419 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-10-15 21:52:00.422 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Thank you so much for all your help, this is much appreciated.
My login.jsp file is as follows:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/taglibs.jsp" %>

<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden"
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
</form>

My taglibs.jsp file is as follows:
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>


My LoginController.java is as follows:
package elements.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/login",
            method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

}

The error I am getting using the trace is as follows:
024-10-16 19:51:21.772 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-10-16 19:51:21.819 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Saved request http://localhost:8080/?continue to session
2024-10-16 19:51:21.820 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-10-16 19:51:21.854 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /login
2024-10-16 19:51:21.877 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /login
2024-10-16 19:51:21.879 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-10-16 19:51:21.887 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to elements.controllers.LoginController#login()
2024-10-16 19:51:21.939 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/png, image/svg+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2024-10-16 19:51:21.941 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.view.InternalResourceView - View name [login], model {}
2024-10-16 19:51:21.955 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name [login]; URL [login]]
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [login]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)


You partially applied my answer from your previous question. Ditch that PasswordEncoder field and constructor those aren't needed. I suspect you are being redirected to /error which is also protected. So you want a permitAll on /error as well. If that doesn't help, enable DEBUG logging and check your logs.

@M.Deinum Thank you so much for all your help. I have updated the code in line with your comments and also used the DEBUG logging to collect all the logs. I will post the updated code and some of the logging below for your perusal as the error still persist.

Is that your actual login page? Or are you retrieving other resources as well (like images etc.) as those would be protected. Try running with TRACE that will tell you which URL leads back to the login page.

@M.Deinum, I have now added the login page and also added output running with TRACE. Thank you.

Hmm I don't see any TRACE information in your logs. I would expect a list of filters being consulted and the actual error.

I this not the correct command to run?
mvn clean package && java -Dlog4j2.debug=true -Dlog4j2.trace=true -jar target/alloy-search-and-predict-web-interface-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

@M.Deinum the code that I am trying to recompile is an open source code and can be found at https://github.com/GM-King/Alloy_Search_and_Predict_1.0. Probably having full access to all the source code you might be able to know what is causing the error. Thank you so much for all your help. This is much appreciated.

That is a Spring Boot 1.2 application, I really hope you aren't planning on using that. We are about 15 versions ahead a lot has changed. At first glance there is also a lot not right with that project to start with.

@M.Deinum Please I am planning of porting it to a modern Spring Boot version for use. Is it not possible with little effort or it will require a lot effort to do it? Thank you.
